# Uploading of file test case written in robot class Not happening in jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver

I am facing issue in uploading file test case.In my test case,i want to upload file.I have written code using robotic and webdriver.Uploading of file works fine when i run in my local machine.Same not works when i run in jenkins.

Comment: robotic? did you means robot class of java?

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you should avoid using a robot to simulate keystrokes. The simulated keystrokes won't work when your srcipt is running on a headless browser.

Comment: What else i can use.Clien is specific on robot class

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.UploadButton-input")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.UploadButton-input")).sendKeys("FileLocation");